# Formatting a Binding<String> that's within my TextField

Tags: swiftui, swift5

I'm using a TextField to collect a User's phone number. I'd like this field to be nicely formatted in a way that, instead of displaying `1234567890` on the frontend, the field is formatted like `123 - 456 - 7890`. I've been searching for the last hour or so and am struggling to find any sort of direction to what I'd imagine was a simple task.

Here's a basic idea of what my TextField looks like: `TextField("", text: $phoneNumber)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up utilizing https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit to get this to work. I used this gist https://gist.github.com/jbnunn/dab656b53f6e4ee2f53730f0b8daee64 to integrate it with SwiftUI.

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides a phone number support by default for TextField (but this will not add the '-' between numbers as this is different in different parts of the world - this is my guess):

```
TextField("", text: $phoneNumber)
.textContentType(.telephoneNumber)
.keyboardType(.phonePad)
```

Comment: Right. I guess the main thing I'm looking to do is add the hyphen and target US populations for now.